# Free 2 and 3d simulators

Tags: simulation, simulator

What physics simulators exist which are open source/free? AI Gym uses a proprietary for-cost physics engine making it nonviable.

Comment: what internet searches have you done? ... how did the results fail to satisfy your inquiry?

Comment: -Gazebo is hard to use. I don't know anything about webots which was the only other one. But it looks borderline properitery also. The MS robotics studio idk if it is still active or not.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* FourierFlux, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.

Comment: Questions like this are welcome in [chat] when you have the [privilege](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for as I am understanding your question, you are asking about open source physics engines for simulation, So here's a short list: 
1. Box2D,
2. Bullet Physics,
3. Chipmunk,
4. Chrono::Engine,
5. DynaMo,
6. Moby (Physsim),
7. Newton Game Dynamics,
8. Open Dynamics Engine,
9. Open Physics Abstraction Layer,
10. OpenTissue.

Comment: Thanks, I tried pybullet but there aren't any sensors actually built into it, that's probably the same with the other ones also. Not sure why Ben has an issue with this since simulators are a core part of robotics.